# Adding a centered axis (4 quadrants) in MATLAB R2014b

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a function while showing the four quadrants. I understand there were previous workarounds with listeners and what nots but the other "solutions" were given over 3 years ago. I liked the clean undocumented solution:

```
%// vertical line
hx = graph2d.constantline(0, 'LineStyle',':', 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hx,'x');

%// horizontal line
hy = graph2d.constantline(0, 'Color',[.7 .7 .7]);
changedependvar(hy,'y');
```

Unfortunately, it does not work any more in Matlab R2014b.

Is there an official way to achieve this kind of plot in MATLAB R2014b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the undocumented option for Matlab 2014b is:

```
h=get(gca);
h.YBaseline.Visible = 'on';
h.XBaseline.Visible = 'on'; 
h.YBaseline.Color =  [0.7 0.7 0.7];
h.XBaseline.Color =  [0.7 0.7 0.7];
h.XBaseline.LineStyle = ':'
h.YBaseline.LineStyle = ':'
```

a different solution you can use is this (no need for the `h=get(gca)` line):

```
matlab.graphics.axis.decorator.Baseline('BaseValue',0, 'Parent',gca, 'Axis',0, 'Visible','on','Color',[0.7 0.7 0.7],'LineStyle',':')
matlab.graphics.axis.decorator.Baseline('BaseValue',0, 'Parent',gca, 'Axis',1, 'Visible','on','Color',[0.7 0.7 0.7],'LineStyle',':')
```

Alternatively, you can use this documented trick after your code, as it automatically scales according to the plots you have:

```
h=get(gca); hold on
line(h.XLim,[0 0],'LineStyle',:,'Color',[0.7 0.7 0.7]); 
line([0 0],h.YLim,'LineStyle',:,'Color',[0.7 0.7 0.7]); hold off
```

As usual, credit to Yair Altman that uncovers these undocumented features in his [blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/).

Comment: Thanks, the second option was just what I was looking for. Note that the third option won't scale dynamically if you change the axis later or let the user drag the plot (with the hand tool)